# Can I detect whether the video display on a windows PC is HDCP enabled in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drm, hdcp

I am developing a WPF application which will play a protected video in a windows media player instance. I have to ensure that the display device is HDCP enabled before playing the video. If the device isn't HDCP enabled, video playing is not allowed.

How can i do this in c# in WPF application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight has `VideoOutputConnector.CanEnableHdcp` but AFAIK in WPF you have to use interop.

Here's an [MSDN article on using Output Protection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd389296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#UsingHDCPProtectContent).